# Select with inner distincts

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I use MSSQL and I a table like this:

```
ID   |   Value1   |   Value2 
1    |     ABC    |   AAA 
2    |     ABC    |   AAA
3    |     XYZ    |   AAA
4    |     ABC    |   BBB
5    |     ABC    |   BBB
6    |     ABC    |   BBB
```

Now I want to count, based on Value2 how many times I have the same entry in Value1. In practical terms, I need a resulting Select like following:

```
 Value2  |   Value1   |  Count
   AAA   |     ABC    |    2
   AAA   |     XYZ    |    1
   BBB   |     ABC    |    3
```

I hope its clear enough? It should work with 2 distincts, right?

Comment: Is this Microsoft SQL Server (as in the first line of the question) or MySQL (as tagged)?  And, this is a basic `group by` query, which is standard SQL.  Have you tried anything?

Comment: [Maybe this will help](http://www.sqlcourse.com/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select value2, value1, count(*)
from table1
group by value2, value1
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b117d4/2)

Answer (score 1):

**Can you please try this:**

```
select value2,value1,count(*) as Count from tablename group by Value2 ,value1
```

group by is an aggregate operator used for grouping rows

Hope this helps..

Comment: No Problem ..Welcome :)..Please upvote..if it is working for you..so that it will be helpful for others reference in future

Comment: I would like, but i need 3 more points to have enough reputation in order to upvote things...